# When does one replace "le/les" with the pronoun "se"?

Tags: pronombres, español-neutral, verbo-pronominal, clíticos

When are the object pronouns *le/les* replaced with *se*?

Comment: I have removed the second sentence from your question... it would make for a better question all on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indirect object pronouns *le* & *les* change to *se* when preceding the direct object pronouns *lo, la, los* & *las*.

> I give it to him- *Se lo doy.*

(can't be *Le lo doy*)

> She tells her mom the truth--She tells it to her.  *Se la dice.*

*Se* is also used "impersonally" when it means "one" (in general).

> One can buy milk here= *Se puede comprar leche aquí.*

Comment: To say "se" means "one" is inaccurate.  "Se puede" is the reflexive construction.  "Milk is sold here" would be "La leche se vende aquí" which is the same verb construction, but there's obviously no "one" to be translated in this case.

Comment: @Flimzy `Se puede comprar leche aquí` it's perfect valid, and for me what I'd use in a normal conversation, I think is a differences between cultures

Comment: @Toni thanks for answering. Can you also tell more about passive voice usage like in the sentence Flimzy mentioned "Milk is sold here" or "The door is being opened by me" etc?

Comment: @EmilioGort: Of course it's valid. I'm not saying it's not. I'm saying that 'se' doesn't translate to 'one'.

Comment: @Curious: What do you want to know about such sentences?

Comment: @Flimzy, thanks for the reply! I would like to know if se can be used in passive voice sentences like these.

Comment: @Curious: The short answer: "Yes!" For a longer answer, I would suggest asking a question on how to use 'se' in passive expressions, as that is a separate question than the one asked here.

Comment: I understand the objection to saying that "se" means "one".  However, I think it's right to say that the reflexive construct often expresses, in Spanish, the same thing that, in Britain, the use of the impersonal pronoun "one" expresses.  Note that the use of the impersonal "one" is unusual in the US, and would probably only be recognized by people who read some British writings.  The impersonal "one" may be derived from the the French "on".

Comment: @Flimzy thanks, I'll go ahead and add that question.

Comment: Toni, I think you meant "preceding," not "proceeding."  (And "proceding" isn't a word.)  "Preceding" means "coming before."

Answer (score 3):

As @toni mentioned the use of le/les or se depends on the type of the Object Pronouns (direct vs. indirect [pronombres](/questions/tagged/pronombres)):

DO Pronouns: *me, te, **lo/la**, nos, os, **los/las***

IO Pronounce: *me, te, **le**, nos, os, **les***

When both are used in the same sentence, like here:

> Ella te los dan.
> *She gives them to you.*
> IO: te
> DO: los
>
> Él me lo dice. 
> *He tells it to me*.
> IO: me
> DO: lo

change the first pronoun to '*se*' if both start with an '*l*':

> Incorrect: No le lo tengo.
> Correct: No **se lo** tengo.
> *I don't have it.*
>
> Incorrect: Él le los muestra a ella.
> Correct: Él **se los** muestra a ella.
> *He shows them to her.*

In such cases you should always try to avoid ambiguous meanings, like:

> Él se los muestra. *To whom???* - *"a ella"*

Here **se** can refer to Él, Ella or even Ellos or Ellas.

Additional examples (mind I'm not native and can be wrong):

> Mi gato está loco por su cola. Siempre **se le** persigue!
> *My cat is crazy about its tail. It always chases it!*
> IO: le
> DO: se
>
> But:
> Mi gato tiene un pelaje bueno. Los cazadores **lo** persiguen para **matarlo**.
> *My cat has a nice fur. Hunters chase it to kill it.*
> DO: le
> DO: matarlo

Comment: Or even *usted* or *ustedes*, adding to the potential confusion.

Comment: @Nat thanks for answering. Can you also tell more about passive voice usage like in the sentence "The door is being opened by me", "The mouse is chased by it (a cat)"? etc.

Comment: @Curious I would rather translate the two sentences you gave with Present Participle (Gerund): "El gato está persiguiendo al ratón. (El ratón está persiguiendo por el gato.)", because they imply continuous actions. You could actually use DO/IO by saying "The cat chases it" -> "El gato se le persigue.", but you'll need to have "the mouse" mentioned and defined earlier in the speech.

Comment: Note for anyone reading this old thread: Nat's comment has problems (but his answer looks good to me).

Comment: Except for "No se lo tengo," which makes no sense to me.  Better: "No se lo doy."