# Why "se lo" instead of "le lo"? / ¿Por qué debo escoger "se lo" en vez de "le lo"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos, verbo-pronominal

In this (simple) sentence:

> **Se** lo dijo la historia. (He told her the story.)

I think this is also right:

> **Le** lo dijo la historia.

But the latter doesn't seem so prevalent or even acceptable. **What's the reason for that?**

---

En esta oración simple:

> **Se** lo dijo la historia.

Pienso también esa es correcto:

> **Le** lo dijo la historia.

Sino la última no parece tan frecuente o aún admisible. ¿**Por qué** es esa cosa? (No pregunto de "cuándo", sino pregunto de "porqué".)

Comment: Your example seems incorrect. A proper one would be just "Se lo dijo" ("He/she told him/her about it") instead of "Le lo dijo". But the question itself is a good one.

Comment: @Charlie I know it's wrong but I don't know why. That's the question.

Comment: To begin with, the proper translation of, "he told her the story", would be: > (Él) Le contó la historia (a ella). So the "Se" would never be used in that specific sentence.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does one replace "le/les" with the pronoun "se"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/when-does-one-replace-le-les-with-the-pronoun-se)

Comment: @aparente001 and other close-voters This is not a duplicate, iBug is asking **why** not **when**. This is a puzzling issue for non native speakers but the rule is so natural for native ones that most do not question it like Pablo's answer shows: *Why ? Because it's just like that*.

Comment: You can't use `le lo`, `la lo`, or even `lo lo`.... so you have to `se lo`

Comment: @dockeryZ Lol for `lo lo`. Maybe we *could* say "Dálolo" or even "Dálala", which makes people think I'm a freak :)

Answer (score 7):

You were already answered the question **when to use *se lo*** but I understand your question is more **why using *se lo*** instead of the expected ***le lo***?

Like a lot of people, I wrongly believed this irregularity was due to euphonious reasons, ***le lo*** being considered unpleasing to the ear.

> ***Le** digo una cosa* = I tell something to you
>
> ***Lo** digo* = I tell it

but

> <s>***Le lo** digo*</s>

becomes

> ***Se lo** digo* = I tell it to you

Same in the imperative mood:

> *Dílo* = Tell it
>
> *Di**me*** = Tell me
>
> *Dí**me**lo* = Tell it to me
>
> *Di**le*** = Tell him
>
> *Dí**se**lo* = Tell it to him

However, there is no real cacophony in *lelo*, the first name *Lola* or the substantive *pelele* (dummy) do not present any problem in Spanish, not to mention *lelo* exists in Spanish both as a substantive and an adjective.

One way to understand why Spanish uses *selo* is to look at the Italian usage:

> *Dimmelo* = *Dímelo*
>
> *Di**gli*** = *Dile* = Tell him
>
> *Di**llo*** = *Dilo* = Tell it
>
> *Di**glielo*** = *Díselo* = Tell it to him

The pronoun starts with an [ʎ] sound. It is coming from the Latin ***illi***.

Similarily, ***illi*** gave ***ge*** \ʒe\ in ancient Spanish so the old form was

> *Dí**ge**lo*

The alternative form *dí**se**lo* superseded the former and is now the norm:

*Real Academia Española de la lengua, Nueva gramática de la
lengua española*, Madrid, Espasa Libros, 2009

> *Téngase en cuenta que una vez que se llega a la forma gelo, con prepalatal sorda, quedaban abiertas dos opciones : la velarización, que seguiría un proceso natural desde el punto de vista fonológico, pero crearía una forma pronominal
> aislada, y la asimilación analógica a las combinaciones con el reflexivo, que se vio facilitada por la proximidad fonética de la prepalatal con la retrofleja.*

Source (if you read French) : [De la morphosyntaxe du pronom complément indirect en espagnol : * Le lo, ge lo, se lo](http://revues.univ-tlse2.fr/reflexos/index.php?id=244&file=1)

Comment: And it's confusing to the ear, too. Se lo is so much clearer and easier to understand.

Comment: I agree the question is about why, by actually the *se lo* originates from much older phonetic stuff unrelated to the apparent cacophony of *le lo*. I don't have time to post an answer right now though

Comment: @guifa Yes, that's right. After some research I found the actual origin of this *se*. Answer updated, Thanks !

Comment: +1 for fluid examples

Comment: Note guifa did get around to posting an answer.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you see *le* transform in front of *lo/la/los/las* has to do with the history of Spanish.   In Old Spanish, the combination **le<sub>(s)</sub> + lo<sub>/a/os/as</sub>** was written **gelo<sub>/a/os/as</sub>** (with the *g* pronounced as [ʒ], as in the first consonant of *azure* or the second consonant in *equation*).  The palatization came about from the Latin *illi illum* that progressed to *(e)liélo*, to *llelo* and then finally to *gelo*.

That much is well established.  What is less known is exactly what caused the transformation such that the *-s* in *les* disappeared.  It definitely had a tendency to disappear in some other places (cf. Portuguese *<sup>nos</sup>/<sub>vos</sub> + o(s) = <sup>no-lo(s)</sup>/<sub>vo-la(s)</sub>*, or Castilian *vamos + nos = vámonos*) but in this particular case it only happened in front of /l/.  Menéndez Pidal felt that that came from Leonese influence (although modern Leonese languages don't do that: Asturianu *dio-yoslu* = Castilian *se<sub>(les)</sub> lo dio*), but that's not settled.

As the [ʒ] sound fell out of use in Spanish around the year 1500, *gelo<sub>/a/os/as</sub>* quickly ended up as *selo<sub>/a/os/as</sub>*, and then was separated out graphically again in *se lo<sub>/a/os/as</sub>*.

Answer (score 3):

Your examples do not mean what you mean to say, but leaving that aside, your issue is with why you must say *se lo* and not *le lo* (or *lo le*). The answer is: because it's just like that.

There are a number of clitic (short, non-emphatic) personal pronouns in Spanish. They can be used in verb phrases as direct objects (accusative), or as indirect objects ([dative](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22678/qu%C3%A9-es-un-dativo-cu%C3%A1ntos-hay-cu%C3%A1l-es-su-diferencia-con-los-pronombres-refle/22681#22681)).

The pronouns for the first and second persons, singular and plural, look the same in the accusative and in the dative: *me, te, nos, os* (note that *os* is used only in Spain; it corresponds to the subject pronoun *vosotros*).

The accusative third person pronouns vary in gender and number: they are *lo, la* for masculine and feminine singular, respectively, and *los, las* for the plural. The dative third person pronouns are singular *le* and plural *les* (they do not inflect for gender).

Some verbs (called ditransitive) can take both a direct and an indirect object, and if both of the objects are replaced by pronouns, there are some rules about that. The first rule is that the dative pronoun goes first, then the accusative, so it must be

> *Me lo diste.* = "You gave it to me."

not

> **Lo me diste.*

The same rule applies even if the pronouns go after the verb, as is the case in imperatives:

> *Dámelo.* = "Give it to me."

The rule that concerns you question is that, in addition to the above, the third person dative pronouns *le* and *les* can't be in the same phrase as the third person accusative pronouns *lo, la, los, las*; if they do appear, they change to *se* (which does not inflect for gender or number). So, if in my examples above we wished to change the first person into third person, we will have to change *le* into *se*:

> *Se lo diste.* = "You gave it to him/her."
>   *Dáselo.* = "Give it to him/her."

I gave a few more examples in [a related question about the uses of the pronoun *se*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22653/14627).

Comment: The dative/indirect doesn't always go first.  The order is actually *se*, *te/os*, *me/nos*, *le/les/lo/la/los/las*, or more compactly *se-2nd-1st-3rd*.  It's not common, but if you get "te me", it's impossible to know which is the dative/indirect and which is the accusative/direct.  Likewise, it's possible to end up with "me le", where clearly the second one is the dative/indirect, and the first is the accusative/direct.

Answer (score 2):

> I think this is also right:
>
> *Le lo dijo la historia*.

As some already commented, the second example is wrong. In DPD you can find this explanation:

> [1. Se pronominal](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bsHtgs373D6sirfnKs)
>   Como pronombre personal, invariable en género y número, tiene distintos valores:
>
> a) Variante formal de le(s).
>
> Cuando el pronombre de dativo le(s) precede a alguno de los pronombres de acusativo de tercera persona *lo(s)*, *la(s)*, adopta la forma se: *Les compré caramelos* > *Se los compré*; *Le puse los zapatos* > *Se los puse*.

So in this case you have a dative pronoun (*le*) which is before a accusative pronoun (los). The *le* adopts the form "se" as the rule explains.

Answer (score 1):

When using direct and indirect objects together, if they both begin with the letter L, the L in the indirect object is changed to an S. For example,

> *Él se lo dice a Juan.*

In this case, *le* would replace Juan, but since *le* and *lo* both begin with an L, it is changed to an S.